# ROS services are not building properly

Tags: ros

I am trying to build my custom ROS services. They are inside a another parent package
the structure is as follows:

```
|--catkine_ws
| |--src
| | |--Parent
| | | |--CMakeLists.txt 
| | | |--package.xml
| | | |--ChildA
| | | | |--CMakeLists.txt 
| | | | |--package.xml
| | | | |--srv
| | | | | |--SomeService.srv
| | | |--ChildB
```

The packages are building correctly and I am able to use them in other nodes and packags.
however when I try to use `rossrv list` the custom services do not appear. I think that this is causing some issues when I try to build my Simulink controller and it cannot find the service message definition.

Does any one have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not something trivial e.g. that you forgot to source the workspace in that console? Furthermore (probably unrelated) why do you actually have a `CMakeLists.txt` in the parent directory? I would structure it as a [metapackage](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-ros-for/9781788478953/7189d008-9683-47c5-b612-0a09c4918e65.xhtml), so only put a `package.xml` in there or make it a plain folder only containing the children...

Comment: You've sourced the setup.bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem, while not obvious, the solution was rather simple. I had to change the slightly change the structure of the package by making the parent package a meta package then do some handling to make sure that the sub packages still had access to the cmakes to locate my external packages.